# Firebase Storage Image Displaying Issue

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

I am successfully able to upload an image to firebase and retrieve it also.

My issue is,
I want the uploaded image to not be visible in storage section even for the admin.

Is there a method from which i can Encrypt the Image and store in firebase?

or,

Is there any rules that has to changed for it to work like my requirement?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Storage can be used to store any type of binary data. So if you don't want the images to be visible by a collaborator on the Firebase project, you can encrypt the data on the client that uploads the data and then decrypt the data on any client that reads it.

This requires no changes to the security rules, as those don't access the binary data of the files.

Comment: The answer was clear enough.
Can you help with the encryption techniques?

Comment: What help are you looking for? Note that we can't recommend any specific encryption technique on Stack Overflow, as that's off topic here. And writing the client-side encryption/decryption code for you would be a bit too much. But if you tried writing it yourself and got stuck, that'd be a valid new question to post.